# How rpath and sys/types.h are related?

Tags: gcc, types, cmake, rpath, systypes.h

After adding "-Wl,-rpath,." into CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS next call in CMakeLists started returning false:
check_include_file_cxx(sys/types.h HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H)

How rpath and sys/types.h are related?

Comment: Macro `check_include_file_cxx` actually compiles and links some source code which uses the header requested. So link options are definitely affect on this process.

Comment: As for RPATH settings see CMake wiki [RPATH Handling](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling).